# Populate spring servlet context on start up

Tags: spring, servlets

It may be a duplicate question.

My question is: I want to read a property from properties file and put that in servlet context as soon as I start my application.

Could any one please help me on that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why in servlet context?

Answer (score 4):

Implement Spring's ApplicationListener:

```
@Component
public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener  {

  /* if you want to set predefined properties you even don't have to load properties filed - you can directly inject properties values ... you can configure it in applicationContext.xml
   <util:list id="locations">
      <value>classpath:appconfig1.properties</value>
      <value>classpath:appconfig2.properties</value>
   </util:list>
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
              p:locations-ref="locations" />
  */         

  @Value("${myproperty1}") private String myProperty1;
  @Value("${myproperty2}") private String myProperty2;
  @Value("${myproperty3}") private String myProperty3;

  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {

    if (event instanceof ContextClosedEvent) {
        applicationClosed();
        return;
    }

    if (!(event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent)) return;
    ContextRefreshedEvent e = (ContextRefreshedEvent) event;
    ApplicationContext appContext = e.getApplicationContext();
    if (!(appContext instanceof WebApplicationContext)) return;
    WebApplicationContext ctx = (WebApplicationContext) e.getApplicationContext();
    ServletContext context = ctx.getServletContext();


    context.setAttribute("myProperty1", myProperty1);
    context.setAttribute("myProperty2", myProperty2);
    context.setAttribute("myProperty3", myProperty3);

  }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me but small question: how to you know the event is the servlet context start up event. I did not find that in Spring document.

Comment: The action is applied only if an event is of `ContextRefreshedEvent` type (can be simply understand from the code I provided) and can be done more easily today: `public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` (and Spring will filter events types for you).